# Proof that $(a, b) \mathrel{R} (c, d)$ iff $ad = bc$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $X = \{(a,b) \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z; b \ne 0\}$. We define $(a,b)\mathrel R (c,d)$ iff $ad = bc$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $X$. Which known set do the equivalence classes of the relation form?

---

Any help on solving this please?

Comment: Have you tried showing the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive?

Comment: Note that $(a,b)R (c,d)$ iff $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$$ Can you now guess what the set of equivalence classes is?

Comment: Hint:Recall the definition of rational numbers. $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{a}{b}|a,b\in \mathbb{Z},b\ne 0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show that the given relation is

- **reflexive**
   For all $(a, b) \in X$, $ab = ba$. This is clearly true. Hence R is reflexive.
- **symmetric** 
   For all $(a, b), (c, d) \in X$, suppose $(a, b) R(c, d).$ Then $ad = bc $ if and only if $cb = da$ if and only if $(c, d) R (a,b)$. Therefore, R is 
  symmetric.
- **transitive**
   Now, see what you can do with the following: Take arbitrary $(a, b), (c, d), (e, f)$ and assume $(a, b)R (c, d)$, and $(c, d) R (e, f)$. So 
  $$ad = bc,\quad \text{and} \quad cf = de$$ Now, we use a little algebra to show that this implies $af = be$, and hence $(a, b) R (e, f)$. 
   $ad = bc \iff adf = bcf = b(cf).$ Also, we have $cf = de$. So $adf = b(de) \iff af = be$, as desired!

The relation has all three properties, and hence, is by definition, an equivalence relation.

---

Hint: $$(a, b) R (c, d) \;\text{ if and only if }\;\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}\; \text{ if and only if } \;ad = bc, \;\;(b\neq 0, d\neq 0)$$

Comment: nice, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Helped me too. p.s. Crazy reputation.

Answer (score 0):

To show this is an equivalence relation, you need to show, for pairs $(a,b),(c,d), (e,f)$:

i)$(a,b)R(a,b)$, for any pair $(a,b)$
ii) If $(a,b)R(c,d)$ , then $(c,d)R(a,b)$
iii)If $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(e,f)$ , then $(a,b)R(e,f)$.

Can you see how to it?

Let's set up i): We want to show that, for any pair $(a,b)$ , i.e., for any choice of integers $a,b$ , we have $(a,b)R(a,b)$. This means that, according to the definition of $R$, we have:

$(a,b)R(a,b)$ iff $ab=ba$ . Can you do the rest?

Comment: What numbers should I pick?

Comment: It is supposed to be true for any choice of numbers. So try assuming that $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are any integers. Can you see how?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that $$(a,b)R(c,d)\quad \text{ iff }\quad ad = bc\quad \text{ iff }\quad\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$$
and since $=$ is an equivalence relation, $R$ is an equivalence one, and  $\mathbb{Q}$ is an example of such classes.