# On Z x Z, let (a,b) R (c,d) if ad=cb. Is this an equivalence relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I can show that this is an equivalence relation given that $b \ne 0$.

My question: Is it true that this relation is NOT an equivalence relation if we don't have the condition $b \ne 0$, because if $b=0$, then that would lead to division by 0, which is undefined?

Comment: Do you know the three axioms of an equivalence relation? Then you can check whether or not $b\neq 0$ matters (transitivity!). Everything can be looked up at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611902/proof-that-a-b-mathrelr-c-d-iff-ad-bc-is-an-equivalence-relation).

Comment: I do know the axioms. When I check for transitivity between (a,b), (c,d), (e,f), I get afd=bde. I can only go on to show that af=be, if d is not zero. I'm just confused about whether or not it would be correct to say that that it's not an equivalnace relation if d is zero

Comment: Can you find three pairs where transitivity does not hold then with $b=0$?

Comment: Yes, I got it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to adjoin "infinity' to the set of rational numbers by introducing  the class of $[(1,0)]$, and also you are trying to define $0/0$ by introducing $[(0,0)]$.
 The problem is that, by definition $(0,0)$ is related to all (a,b), therefor the transitivity will be violated.

For example you will have $(3,5)R (0,0)$ and $(0,0)R(4,5)$ without $(3,5)R(4,5)$